# valuation to a function using a list

Tags: functions

What I want to do is to evaluate a function as shown below:

```
LessQ[n_] := LessQ[n] = l[n] < 61
```

In some cases, when I am sure that on a list the `LessQ[]` is True, I want to

```
LessQ[#]& = True/@{1,2,3,4}
```

but this doesn’t work. So, instead of using a `For[]` loop, is there any other method?

Comment: Do you want to map `LessQ` over the list, comparing each element, or do you have some defined way of saying that one list is "less than" another? What is `l[n]`?

Comment: Use `Scan[]`: `Scan[(LessQ[#] = True) &, {1, 2, 3, 4}]`. Note the parenthesization and the placement of the function operator (`&`).

Comment: thanks so much , Ox4A4D,that is exactly what I am going to find